# Google Drive Python API authorization using service account key

Tags: python, oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have the following service account json credentials file for a Google Cloud Platform project:

[image]

How would I authenticate to Google Drive API using this service account? For example, when I try doing the following:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('mykey.json', SCOPES)
creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

results = service.files().list(pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
```

I get an error when running the `flow` command that complains about the format of the keyfile not starting with `web` or `installed`:

```
Invalid file format. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
Expected a JSON object with a single property for a "web" or "installed" application
```

Is there a way to use the above key to list my Drive files for my Google Service Account? If so, how would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using service account credentials, the `ServiceAccountCredentials` library should be imported from `oauth2client.service_account` and used as below:

```
# The needed import for service account credentials:
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

from apiclient.discovery import build

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

# Parsing JSON credentials for a service account:
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

Then, use `service` as regular, e.g. `service.files()` etc.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to the following [Python Quickstart for Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) page and click "Enable the Drive API" button. This will allow you to download credentials that are of the format the following line excepts:

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('mykey.json', SCOPES)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how to use the service account credentials, rather than the regular account credentials which are based on user.

Comment: @MeirCohen sure, want to post another answer then and I can accept yours?

Comment: I was just composing my answer while you commmented :)
In case it's still relevant, you may test my suggested code, and accept my answer if it works for you.